# Euro sign in excel export from PHP

Tags: php, html, csv

I have a array in php which i want to export to  csv.

This is working fine except i can't seem to get the euro sign (€) in this export.

It is showing this (â‚¬).

**I already tried it with this :**

```
$text = '&euro;' . $fields['REST_WAARDE'];
$kaart_type = html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
```

and :

```
&euro;

$kaart_type = str_replace('&euro;','€',$kaart_type);
```

and also just a normal :

```
€
```

My headers :

```
    $filename = 'export_klantenkaarten.csv';
    header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = \"$filename\"");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: The `charset=` parameter on the HTTP header won't be passed to Excel, so Excel has to guess the encoding based only on the file name and contents. In my experience, it's CSV import filter is not great, so probably doesn't try very hard, and assumes a single-byte codeset like Windows-1252.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
$text = '€: some text';
$filename = 'export_klantenkaarten.csv';
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = \"$filename\"");
print chr(255) . chr(254) . mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
```